# PROBLEM WITH ANACONDA POWERSHELL PROMPT COMMAND

Tags: python, powershell, anaconda

I have problem with anaconda. Before two hours ago I tried to install mod_wsgi latest version, but it was not successful - unable to build wheels problem, and the error message was about missing project-toml files. I tried to fix this problem with upgrading MS Visual studio, but after that I remembered that the problem is because maybe I used old version of python. However, bigger problem appeared when I tried to start anaconda prompt shell. Next message appear on my screen:

```
Unable to create process using 'C:\Users\Miroslav Ivanov\anaconda3\python.exe "C:\Users\Miroslav Ivanov\anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py" shell.powershell activate "C:\Users\Miroslav Ivanov\anaconda3"'
Invoke-Expression : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Command' because it is an empty string.
At C:\Users\Miroslav Ivanov\anaconda3\shell\condabin\Conda.psm1:76 char:36
+         Invoke-Expression -Command $activateCommand;
+                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Invoke-Expression], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Invo
   keExpressionCommand
```

I uninstalled anaconda and installed it again but the problem remains. Could you please help me?

Comment: There is an error in the parameter name.  I think you are missing the dash with parameter name.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parameters?view=powershell-7.3

Comment: @jdweng, the problem is unrelated to PowerShell and its syntax. The original error is one emitted by Python; a subsequent call to PowerShell's `Invoke-Expression` causes a _follow-up_ error, which isn't a syntax error: it solely stems from `$activateCommand` being `$null`, as a result of the Python call failing. I don't know what causes the Python error, but there are [many similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+%5Banaconda%5D++Unable+to+create+process).

Comment: Miroslav, the problem may be related to the fact that your username has _embedded spaces_, as discussed in [this blog post](https://9to5answer.com/anaconda-quot-failed-to-create-process-quot).

Comment: @mklement0 : The error is due to powershell getting a bad parameter.  The exception clearly states that.

Comment: @jdweng, yes, as explained in my comment, the issue is a _follow-up problem_ from a _preceding Python error_; specifically, the failing Python command results in `$activateCommand` being `$null`, which, in turn, causes `Invoke-Expression` to fail, because its `-Command` parameter requires  a _non-empty string_ as an argument. As such, PowerShell is _wholly incidental_ to the issue at hand, and making unrelated claims about PowerShell _syntax_ issues, as you did, is a confusing distraction.

Comment: Thank you all! I just reinstalled Anaconda in different directory. Problem here is that I have deleted and installed it again a few times I think. So with new directory it is working for now. Once again - thank you a lot!